# nested for, for, if loop in render_template

Tags: python, flask

For some reason, my conditional is not picking up

I tried displaying both items in the loop, and they are appearing to be exactly the same.

```py
regions = {'central':3000,'south':2000}
area = [('main','central',100),('main','central',300),('secondary','south',200)]
{{% for i in regions.items() %}}
    {{%for z in area%}}
        {{%if z[1] == i[0]%}}
              <tr><td>{{z[1]}}</td><td>{{z[2]}}</td></tr>
        {{%endif%}}
    {{%endfor%}}
{{% endfor %}}
```

I am expecting it to print a table with 2 rows.
central100
central300

Before the if z[1] line, I wrote {{z[1]}}{{i[0]}} and I got CentralCentral.

I am getting an error about a missing %.

Comment: when doing codes in flask you only need a single `{ }` for example, `{{% for i in regions.items() %}}` should be just `{% for i in regions.items() %}` and `{{ z[1] }}` is right.

Answer (score 0):

Flask uses Jinja for templating in which the code part goes inside `{% code here %}`
And for rendering variable it uses `{{ variable }}`.
So in your case you have  used `{{% code %}}` for the code part which gives an error.

```
{% for i in regions.items() %}
    {%for z in area%}
        {%if z[1] == i[0]%}
              <tr><td>{{z[1]}}</td><td>{{z[2]}}</td></tr>
        {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

You have to change the syntax like above.